# Haskell http response result unreadable

Tags: http, haskell, encoding

```
import Network.URI
import Network.HTTP
import Network.Browser

get :: URI -> IO String
get uri = do
  let req = Request uri GET [] ""
  resp <- browse $ do
    setAllowRedirects True -- handle HTTP redirects
    request req
  return $ rspBody $ snd resp

main = do
  case parseURI "http://cn.bing.com/search?q=hello" of
    Nothing -> putStrLn "Invalid search"
    Just uri -> do
        body <- get uri
        writeFile "output.txt" body
```

Here is the diff between haskell output and curl output

[image: vimdiff]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's probably not a good idea to use `String` as the intermediate data type here, as it will cause character conversions both when reading the HTTP response, and when writing to the file. This can cause corruption if these conversions are nor consistent, as it would appear they are here.

Since you just want to copy the bytes directly, it's better to use a `ByteString`. I've chosen to use a lazy `ByteString` here, so that it does not have to be loaded into memory all at once, but can be streamed lazily into the file, just like with `String`.

```
import Network.URI
import Network.HTTP
import Network.Browser
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L

get :: URI -> IO L.ByteString
get uri = do
  let req = Request uri GET [] L.empty
  resp <- browse $ do
    setAllowRedirects True -- handle HTTP redirects
    request req
  return $ rspBody $ snd resp

main = do
  case parseURI "http://cn.bing.com/search?q=hello" of
    Nothing -> putStrLn "Invalid search"
    Just uri -> do
        body <- get uri
        L.writeFile "output.txt" body
```

Fortunately, the functions in `Network.Browser` are overloaded so that the change to lazy bytestrings only involves changing the request body to `L.empty`, replacing `writeFile` with `L.writeFile`, as well as changing the type signature of the function.

Comment: Cool!It solve the problem perfectly. Where can I learn more about the String's behavior?

Comment: @wenlong: It's not so much about `String` as about the functions that work on it. The documentation for `Network.Browser` doesn't mention character encoding at all, so I assume it probably just treats the input as 8-bit code points (i.e. ISO-8859-1), whereas `writeFile` [uses the default encoding on your system](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/System-IO.html#g:23).

Comment: @hammer: If Network.Browser just treats the input as 8-bit, I think we just need to wrap it. For this case, `get :: URI -> IO String`, change  last line of your version `get` to `return $ toString $ respBody $ snd resp`. The get now will produce String.